# Django query using ManytoManyField

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, manytomanyfield

Using example code:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
```

How could I get the name of the last 5  persons and their group's name order by date_joined? Something like:

```
"name1" "group1" "19/02/2019"
"name2" "group1" "19/02/2019"
"name1" "group2" "19/02/2019"
"name3" "group1" "18/02/2019"
"name4" "group2" "17/02/2019"
```

I have tried many options but I am not able to do it :S Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this by following

```
Membership.objects.values('person__name', 'group__name', 'date_joined').order_by(date_joined)[:5]
```

Comment: I got this error : NameError: name 'person__name' is not defined

Comment: I am really sorry, there was a typo in my answer. In values we need to pass field as string. I have updated my answer. Please check and give me a feed back if its not working.

Comment: WOW! I didn't expected that. Thank you for your answer ;)